# Padding unicode strings with bash's printf

Tags: bash, string, unicode, printf

I tried padding a Unicode string with bash's printf, and saw that, while

```
printf "%2s" a
```

yields the expected " a",

a Unicode variant

```
printf "%2s" ä
```

yields a surprisingly unpadded "ä".  (zsh gives the expected result.)

What causes this; and how am I supposed to pad Unicode strings
in bash?

Comment: For those attempting to duplicate: The Z shell needs `LC_CTYPE` to be in a `.UTF-8` locale for the reported behaviour to manifest.

Answer (score 4):

The character `ä` is encoded with 2 bytes in UTF-8, so Printf takes it for 2-padded.

Wc can count the characters (`-m`) and bytes (`-c`) of a string.
The number to give Printf is then `[intended pad]+[bytes]-[chars]`. So I have assembled this `pad.sh` script,

```
#!/bin/sh
bytes=$(printf '%s' "$2" | wc -c)
chars=$(printf '%s' "$2" | wc -m)
n=$(($1+bytes-chars))
printf "%${n}s" "$2"
```

In the example execution below, I have artifficially added newlines
after each output for clarity's sake.

```
$ sh pad.sh 10 abcdef
    abcdef
$ sh pad.sh 10 äéßôçÈ
    äéßôçÈ
```

Answer (score 0):

bash behaves correctly and the C program

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
        char foo[] = "ä";

        printf("%2s\n", foo);
}
```

behaves the same.

This is because %s refers to a byte oriented string and 'ä' in UTF-8 results in 2 bytes.

As far as I could test, none of the other shells behaves incorrect.

The result you expect could be seen with something like:

```
printf '%2S\n' ä
```

but this is not supported by any of the shells I tested.

Answer (score 0):

> how am I supposed to pad Unicode strings in bash?

That's way beyond the capabilities of bash. If you're limiting "Unicode strings" to ascii++ (no double width characters, no bidi, no non-spacing marks, no etc), you may jury-rig something like:

```
% pad(){ printf '%*s%s\n' "$(($1-${#2}))" "" "$2"; }
% pad 2 €
 €
```